# PHP Recursive Array for Blog Comments

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Good day guys.

Please, am working on a blog and I wish to display blog comments and their associated replies in a top-bottom order, i.e

```
Comment A

--->Sub-comments for Comment A

Comment B
---> Sub-comments for Comment B
```

Continuously in that order...

And to achieve the above, I have 3 PHP functions;

The first function checks if the Comment (let's say, Comment A) has sub-comment(s) and returns the count.

```
public function commentHasChildren($blog_id,$parent_id)
{
    $blog_id = $blog_id;
    $parent_id = $parent_id;
    $sql2 = "SELECT count(id) as counter FROM comment WHERE blog_id = '$blog_id' AND parent_id = '$parent_id' AND status = '1'";
    $result2 = $this->db_query($sql2);

    return $result2[0]['counter'];
}
```

The second function get the blog comments and the associated sub-comments

```
public function getBlogComment($blog_id,$parent_id = "")
{
    $id = $blog_id;
    $filter = ($parent_id == "")? "parent_id IS NULL":"parent_id = '$parent_id'";
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE blog_id = '$id' AND status = '1' AND $filter ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = $this->db_query($sql);

    $output = [];
    if(count($result) > 0)
    {
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $counter = $this->commentHasChildren($id, $row['id']);
            $html = $this->getBlogCommentReplyForm($id);
            if ($counter > 0) { //if the blog has sub-comments, append the sub-comments to the comments
                    
                $html .= $this->getBlogCommentReplyForm($id, $row['id']);
            }
            $full_name = $row['full_name'];
            $content = $row['content'];
            $created = $row['created'];
            $parent_id = $row['id'];
            $output[] = [
                "blog_id"=>$id,
                "fullName"=>$full_name,
                "content"=>$content,
                "created"=>$created,
                "parent_id"=>$parent_id,
                "counter"=>count($counter),
                "children"=>$html, 
                "reply"=>$counter  
            ];
        }    
    }
    return $output;
}
```

The third function is meant displays the blog comments and the associated sub-comments

```
public function getBlogCommentReplyForm($blog_id,$parent_id = "")
{
    $id = $blog_id;
    $filter = ($parent_id == "")? "parent_id IS NULL":"parent_id = '$parent_id'";
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE blog_id = '$id' AND status = '1' AND $filter ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = $this->db_query($sql);

    $output = [];
    if(count($result) > 0)
    {
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $comments = '
                <li class="comment">
                    <article class="comment-body">
                        <footer class="comment-meta">
                            <div class="comment-author vcard">
                                <img src="avatar.png" class="avatar" alt="image">
                                <b class="fn">'.$row['full_name'].'</b>
                                <span class="says">says:</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-metadata">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <time>'.date('F d, Y', strtotime($row['created'])).' at '.date('h:m a', strtotime($row['created'])).'</time>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </footer>
                        <div class="comment-content">
                            <p>'.$row['content'].'</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="reply">';?>
                        <?php $reply = (count($result) <= 1) ? ' reply':' replies'?>
                        <?=(count($result) > 0) ? '<kbd class="comment-reply-link">'.count($result).' '.$reply.' </kbd>':''?>
        <?php   $comments .= '
                            <button class="comment-reply-link show-reply-section show-reply-section'.$row['id'].'" data-comment_id="'.$row['id'].'">Reply</button>
                            <button class="comment-reply-link close-reply-section close-reply-section'.$row['id'].'" data-comment_id="'.$row['id'].'">Cancel</button>
                            <div class="comment-respond reply-section reply-section'.$row['id'].'" >
                                <h3 class="comment-reply-title">Leave a Reply</h3>
                                <form class="comment-form" id="post-reply'.$row['id'].'" data-id="'.$row['parent_id'].'" action="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="op" id="op'.$row['id'].'" value="helper.replyComment">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="blog_id" id="blog_id'.$row['id'].'" placeholder="Comment Id" value="'.$blog_id.'">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="parent_id'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['id'].'">
                                    <p class="comment-notes">
                                        <span id="email-notes">Your email address will not be published.</span>
                                            Required fields are marked
                                        <span class="required">*</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="comment-form-comment">
                                        <label>Comment</label>
                                        <textarea name="content" id="content'.$row['id'].'" class="content" cols="45" rows="5" maxlength="65525" ></textarea>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="comment-form-author">
                                        <label>Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" id="full_name'.$row['id'].'" class="full_name" name="full_name">
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="comment-form-email">
                                        <label>Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="email" id="username'.$row['id'].'" class="username" name="username">
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="comment-form-cookies-consent">
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="wp-comment-cookies-consent" checked="" id="wp-comment-cookies-consent'.$row['parent_id'].'">
                                        <label for="wp-comment-cookies-consent">Save my name and email, and send me notifications on posts that are related to this one.</label>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="form-submit">
                                        <button class="submit-reply btn btn-primary">
                                        <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></span> <o class="btn-text">Post Reply</o></button>
                                        <button class="comment-reply-link close-reply-section close-reply-section'.$row['id'].'" data-comment_id="'.$row['id'].'">Cancel</button>
                                        <span class="msg" style="color: white;"></span>
                                    </p>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </li>';
            $output[] = [
                $comments
            ];
        }
    }
    return $comments;
}
```

The first and third functions works perfectly well, my problem is the second function

How do I re-iterate recursively the fetch the comments and associated sub-comments?

Please, any kind of assistance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after much research and efforts, I was able to get the functions to work exactly as expected.

Here's what I later did;

For the Function that gets all the blog comments and the sub-comments

```
public function getBlogComment($blog_id,$parent_id = "")
{
    $id = $blog_id;
    $filter = ($parent_id == "")? "parent_id IS NULL":"parent_id = '$parent_id'";
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM blog_comment WHERE blog_id = '$id' AND status = '1' AND $filter ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = $this->db_query($sql);

    $output = [];
    if(count($result) > 0)
    {
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $counter = $this->commentHasChildren($id, $row['id']);
            if((int)$counter == 1):
                $reply = '<kbd class="comment-reply-link">'.$counter.' reply</kbd>';
            elseif(($counter > 1)):
                $reply = '<kbd class="comment-reply-link">'.$counter.' replies</kbd>';
            else:
                $reply = '';
            endif;

            $comments = '
                <li class="comment">
                    <article class="comment-body">
                        <footer class="comment-meta">
                            <div class="comment-author vcard">
                                <img src="../assets/img/icon.png" class="avatar" alt="image">
                                <b class="fn">'.$row['full_name'].'</b>
                                <span class="says">says:</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-metadata">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <time>'.date('F d, Y', strtotime($row['created'])).' at '.date('h:m a', strtotime($row['created'])).'</time>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </footer>
                        <div class="comment-content">
                            <p>'.$row['content'].'</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="reply">
                            '.$reply.'
                            <button class="comment-reply-link show-reply-section show-reply-section'.$row['id'].'" data-comment_id="'.$row['id'].'">Reply</button>
                            <button class="comment-reply-link close-reply-section close-reply-section'.$row['id'].'" data-comment_id="'.$row['id'].'">Cancel</button>
                            <div class="comment-respond reply-section reply-section'.$row['id'].'" >
                                <h3 class="comment-reply-title">Leave a Reply</h3>
                                <form class="comment-form" id="post-reply'.$row['id'].'" data-id="'.$row['parent_id'].'" action="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="op" id="op'.$row['id'].'" value="helper.replyComment">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="blog_id" id="blog_id'.$row['id'].'" placeholder="Comment Id" value="'.$blog_id.'">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="parent_id'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['id'].'">
                                    <p class="comment-notes">
                                        <span id="email-notes">Your email address will not be published.</span>
                                            Required fields are marked
                                        <span class="required">*</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="comment-form-comment">
                                        <label>Comment</label>
                                        <textarea name="content" id="content'.$row['id'].'" class="content" cols="45" rows="5" maxlength="65525" ></textarea>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="comment-form-author">
                                        <label>Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" id="full_name'.$row['id'].'" class="full_name" name="full_name">
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="comment-form-email">
                                        <label>Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="email" id="username'.$row['id'].'" class="username" name="username">
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="comment-form-cookies-consent">
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="wp-comment-cookies-consent" checked="" id="wp-comment-cookies-consent'.$row['parent_id'].'">
                                        <label for="wp-comment-cookies-consent">Save my name and email, and send me notifications on posts that are related to this one.</label>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="form-submit">
                                        <button class="submit-reply btn btn-primary">
                                        <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></span> <o class="btn-text">Post Reply</o></button>
                                        <button class="comment-reply-link close-reply-section close-reply-section'.$row['id'].'" data-comment_id="'.$row['id'].'">Cancel</button>
                                        <span class="msg" style="color: white;"></span>
                                    </p>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>';
                if ((int)$counter > 0):
                    $comments .= $this->getBlogCommentReplyForm($id, $row['id']);
                else:
                    $comments .= '</li>';
                endif;

            $html = $comments;

            $output[] = [
                "children"=>$html  
            ];
        }    
    }
    return $output;
}
```

And for the other function that returns all the associated sub-comment's replies

```
public function getBlogCommentReplyForm($blog_id,$parent_id)
{
    $id = $blog_id;
    // $filter = ($parent_id == "")? "parent_id IS NULL":"parent_id = '$parent_id'";
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM blog_comment WHERE blog_id = '$id' AND status = '1' AND parent_id='$parent_id' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = $this->db_query($sql);

    $comments = '';

    if(count($result) > 0)
    {
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $counter = $this->commentHasChildren($id, $row['id']);
            if((int)$counter == 1):
                $reply = '<kbd class="comment-reply-link">'.$counter.' reply</kbd>';
            elseif((int)$counter > 1):
                $reply = '<kbd class="comment-reply-link">'.$counter.' replies</kbd>';
            else:
                $reply = '';
            endif;

            $comments .='
                <ol class="children" id="children'.$id.'">
                    <article class="comment-body">
                        <footer class="comment-meta">
                            <div class="comment-author vcard">
                                <img src="../assets/img/icon.png" class="avatar" alt="image">
                                <b class="fn">'.ucwords($row['full_name']).'</b>
                                <span class="says">says:</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-metadata">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <time>'.date('F d, Y', strtotime($row['created'])).' at '.date('h:m a', strtotime($row['created'])).'</time>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </footer>
                        <div class="comment-content">
                            <p>'.$row['content'].'</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="reply">
                            '.$reply.'
                            <button class="comment-reply-link show-reply-section show-reply-section'.$row['id'].'" data-comment_id="'.$row['id'].'">Reply</button>
                            <button class="comment-reply-link close-reply-section close-reply-section'.$row['id'].'" data-comment_id="'.$row['id'].'">Cancel</button>
                            <div class="comment-respond reply-section reply-section'.$row['id'].'" >
                                <h3 class="comment-reply-title">Leave a Reply</h3>
                                <form class="comment-form" id="post-reply'.$row['id'].'" data-id="'.$row['parent_id'].'" action="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="op" id="op'.$row['id'].'" value="helper.replyComment">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="blog_id" id="blog_id'.$row['id'].'" placeholder="Comment Id" value="'.$blog_id.'">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="parent_id'.$row['id'].'" value="'.$row['id'].'">
                                    <p class="comment-notes">
                                        <span id="email-notes">Your email address will not be published.</span>
                                            Required fields are marked
                                        <span class="required">*</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="comment-form-comment">
                                        <label>Comment</label>
                                        <textarea name="content" id="content'.$row['id'].'" class="content" cols="45" rows="5" maxlength="65525" ></textarea>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="comment-form-author">
                                        <label>Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="text" id="full_name'.$row['id'].'" class="full_name" name="full_name">
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="comment-form-email">
                                        <label>Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="email" id="username'.$row['id'].'" class="username" name="username">
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="comment-form-cookies-consent">
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="wp-comment-cookies-consent" checked="" id="wp-comment-cookies-consent'.$row['parent_id'].'">
                                        <label for="wp-comment-cookies-consent">Save my name and email, and send me notifications on posts that are related to this one.</label>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="form-submit">
                                        <button class="submit-reply btn btn-primary">
                                        <span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></span> <o class="btn-text">Post Reply</o></button>
                                        <button class="comment-reply-link close-reply-section close-reply-section'.$row['id'].'" data-comment_id="'.$row['id'].'">Cancel</button>
                                        <span class="msg" style="color: white;"></span>
                                    </p>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>';
                if ((int)$counter > 0):
                    // var_dump(json_encode($row));
                    // var_dump($comments);
                    $comments .= $this->getBlogCommentReplyForm($id, $row['id']);
                    $comments .='</ol>';
                else:
                    $comments .='</ol></li>';
                endif;


        }
    }
    return $comments;
}
```

I hope you find this useful...